# Alternatives for polling actions in MVC site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nservicebus, polling

We are deploying an ASP.NET MVC site to a host that only allows us to runs sites and windows workflows.

We need to trigger events or poll in order to trigger certain actions.
Preferably we would not use polling since we have quite a bit of data to go through.
The trigger intervals range from everything from 12hours to 5 years but we do know exactly how long to wait for each trigger.

What options do we have here?
My first thought was to use NServiceBus and use future messages, but it turns out that we can not deploy this to the host. so no luck.

Can WF be used to trigger this kind of timed actions?

Ideas here?

Comment: Have you looked at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), which can 'push' messages from the server to the client?

Comment: Yes, but the thing here is that we have big time spans to take into account, e.g. 5 years, so there needs to be some sort of persistence mechanism involved. and I guess hosting that sort of process inside a website would be problematic (?) e.g. app pool idle'ing out

Comment: What is the issue of hosting NServiceBus in IIS?

Comment: Nice, didn't know that was an option.. I have to look up if we have access to msmq on the host, or are there other bus options that works if we only have access to sql server?

Comment: Can the subscriber actually live in the IIS process and run there on its own? or would it just be endpoints that use NSB?

Comment: You can use the Sql Server Transport for NSB. With that you don't need MSMQ. Or you simply use Quartz.NET or any other scheduling framework.

Comment: You may want to opt for a scheduling component.  Our FOSS service bus (https://github.com/Shuttle/shuttle-esb) has a scheduler (https://github.com/Shuttle/shuttle-scheduling) but you should go with what you are comfortable with.